# The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved (only in runtime)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Maven build is completing successfully, but when the war is run in Apache tomcat 7, it gives the following error:

`java.lang.Error`: Unresolved compilation problems:

The import `javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream` cannot be resolved

Comment: If you get `Unresolved compilation problems`, then your Maven build did **not** complete successfully. How could you think that a compilation error is *successful*?

Comment: try this: <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Even after adding that dependency, Maven is always giving build as successful, but when I open the .class file, it shows this error.